# Let $A$ be a matrix of size $5\times 5$ with rank(A)=3 .Prove that there exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have to prove that the rank of the matrix $B=2$ and given that $B$ is a $5\times 5$ non zero matrix.

My attempt :
Let the columns of $B$ be $X_1,X_2,...,X_5$.Then $AX_1=0$,$AX_2=0$,...,$AX_5=0$.Now since the rank of the matrix $A$ is given as $3$ .So there are $2$ free variables and the possible dimensions of $X_1,..,X_5$ are $2$.

Hence combining we can find the possible rank of $B$ is 2 .

Where am I going wrong in the proof?Also I have not been taught linear transformation so I cannot use it here.

Comment: Why don't you take $B=0$?

Comment: If you want to restrict what cannot be used, it would likely be more helpful to explain what can be used. IE Are we allowed to use matrix theory about dimensions?

Comment: Yes @Calvin we can use that but am I going wrong?

Comment: If $AB = 0$, what can you say about the dimensions of their kernels?

Comment: Yes, but looking at the matrix $B$ in this way where am I going wrong?

Comment: You do not really explain why such a matrix exists. You only determined its rank given it exists.

Comment: "*I have to prove that the rank of the matrix $B=2$*"  You can't do that because the rank of $B$ could be strictly less than $2$.  You can prove however that the rank of $B$ is *at most 2*, but that is a different statement.  Alternatively, you could prove that there *exists a rank 2 matrix $B$ such that $AB=0$* or similar.

Comment: Now... as for approaching this for arbitrary $A$... given that $A$ is a $5\times 5$ matrix of rank $3$... we know by the rank-nullity theorem that $A$ has nullity $2$.  That is to say, the nullspace (*a.k.a. the kernel*) of $A$ is of dimension $2$.  Suppose that $\{u,v\}$ is a basis for the kernel of $A$.  Now... let us define a matrix which we call $B$ whose columns are $u,v$ and three copies of the zero vector.  Can we conclude anything about $AB$ given this information?  Why?

Answer (score 3):

$B$ can be any $5 \times k$ matrix whose columns are in the null space of $A$ which is 2 dimensional. So $B$ has rank at most $2$.